# How can I redirect people accessing my files as directories?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following situation:

On my webserver I have an instance of websvn running, where specific repositories and revisions can be accessed by a URL like

`http://www.myhost.com/listing.php?repname=repository1&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fbackend`

Somehow, out there in the wild, a wrong URL is being used to access this

`http://www.myhost.com/listing.php/?repname=repository1&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fbackend`

(Notice the slash after listing.php)

Now, although the URL works and websvn still shows the webpage, images and stylesheets do not get loaded correctly, since they are referenced relative.

I tried to add an .htaccess file to the webroot to redirect people accessing the file as directory to the correct URL.

I have tried multiple variations and ended up with this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/listing.php/ listing.php [R=301,QSA]
```

But, since I am writing here, you already guessed it: It doesn't work.

I also tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/listing.php(.*) listing.php$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, I recommend changing the 301 to a 307 until you get it working. Otherwise, your browser will cache the 301 result, redirecting on subsequent references without consulting your server, and likely giving you very confusing results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps among other things, a `RewriteRule` within `.htaccess` that starts with “`^/`” will never match anything at all. (Examples that include a leading slash are for the global configuration file.) Remove the leading forward slash and see if that helps.

Also, I recommend changing the 301 to a 307 until you get it working. Otherwise, your browser will cache the 301 result, redirecting on subsequent references without consulting your server at all and likely giving you very confusing results.

Comment: Thank you. The leading slash was my problem. Now it works as expected!